# What are "Movements methods" in Android ?

Tags: android, string, events, text, textview

I try to do code that, if you click at one of the word of "TextView", this word is modified.

I stumbled upon `ClickableSpan` and `MovementMethod`.

And documentation of `ClickableSpan` says :

> If an object of this type is attached to the text of a TextView with a movement method of LinkMovementMethod

Could you explain to me, what is "Movement method" in general ? What's the purpose of this class ?

Why I need "Movement method" to `TextView` to get click event on my `span`'s ?

Comment: have you read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/MovementMethod.html ?

Comment: @pskink Yeah, but i see no connection with ClickableSpanable.

Comment: see this http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.java, lines 134 and 216